# Donde encuentro el url de la api Google Translate para enlazar con Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Estoy programando una aplicación para Android, la cual consiste en un traductor mediante, la voz, reconocimiento optico y el teclado. Estoy usando las apis de google pero no logro hacer que me fusionen ya que necesito un api key y una url luego de contratar esos servicios de google, pero no se donde generarlos...

Esta es un ejemplo que encontre, esta URL no me sirve y no se donde encontrar la de mis credenciales

Comment: Hey Guillermo E. Rivas, bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del 

sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu 

pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, esto para que 

pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto te sugiero leer 

[ask], saludos!

Comment: No uses imagenes de código agregalo como texto en tu pregunta, especifica lo que has logrado. Modifica tu pregunta por favor.

Comment: [Aquí te lo explican todo](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/getting-started?hl=es)... ¿hiciste esos pasos? ¿te encuentras bloqueado en alguno de ellos o simplemente no lo entiendes en inglés?